# Presenting Word Docs in PDF format in Sharepoint list

Tags: pdf

I have developed a Sharepoint list that has documents attached to each record. Most of them are in Word, but I don't want to present docs in Word to my users. Is there a way to store docs as Word (when you upload them), but to present them as PDF's?
Thanks in advance to all responding!
I have Sharepoint 2016 On-Prem.

Answer (score 2):

for the above you need some conversion of doc to pdf first then create a view on the basis of the extension of the document.There can be two way to convert your word doc to pdf:

1)third party solutions that enable [workflow features like this in SharePoint](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-document-types-using-pdf.html).

2) Or by Converting a Library’s Word Documents to PDF using [Word Automation Services for SharePoint](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/converting-a-librarys-word-documents-to-pdf-using-word-automation-services-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I shall review and report back.